# Java : How to delete files from my local repo after put files in sftp

Tags: java, sftp

I wouldlike to delete files from my local repository after pushing files to my remote file in sftp :

```
 ChannelSftp channelSftp_IDS = createChannelSftp(username, password, host);
 channelSftp_IDS.connect();
        
 String fileLocal  = "/data/readme.txt"
       
 channelSftp_IDS.put(fileLocal, "readme.txt");
         
 channelSftp_IDS.exit();
```

I tried this but it doesn't work : `Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(fileLocal));`

Answer (score 0):

if `fileLocal` is an instance of `java.io.File`, use `fileLocal.delete();`

Comment: we can't do the same with string variable ?

Comment: you'd be deleting a string!? ... if `stringVariable` is an absolute path... i.e. `"c:/dir/file.txt"`, then you can use new `File(stringVariable) delete();`